# Unable to get full code coverage for a SF trigger after update

Tags: apex, trigger, apexrest, after-trigger

I have a simple Apex trigger, written for an object called Application__c, and it fires after the "Shipping_City__c" field changes:

```
    1.trigger MyTrigger on Application__c (after update) {
        
    2.    private String syStudentId;
    3.    private boolean skipStudent;
        
    4.    if(TriggerFirstRunCheck.firstRun){
        
    5.        TriggerFirstRunCheck.firstRun=false;
                                    
            
    6.        for (Application__c app: Trigger.new) {
                
    7.            system.debug('***old city: '+ Trigger.oldMap.get(app.Id).Shipping_City__c);
    8.            system.debug('***new city: '+ app.Shipping_City__c);
    
    9.            if (Trigger.oldMap.get(app.Id).Shipping_City__c != app.Shipping_City__c) {
                       
   10.                   skipStudent = false;                                                        
   11.                  //Run a simple code here
                  }     
                 
               }   
            }  
        }
    }
```

And I have this test method for the trigger:

```
@isTest
    static void testUpdateApplication() {
                            
        Contact con = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestFirstName', LastName ='TestLastName');
        insert con;
                
        Application__c app = new Application__c();
          app.Student__c = con.Id;
          app.Shipping_City__c = 'TestCity';
        
        insert app;
                
        Test.startTest();        
        
        app.Shipping_City__c='NewTestCity';

        update app; 
        
        Test.stopTest();


        System.assertEquals('NewTestCity', app.Shipping_City__c, 'City Failed!');        

    }
```

The test method successfully passes and it means that Shipping_City__c gets updated. But the problem is that I have only 40% code coverage for the trigger and that's because in the System.debug lines(lines 7 and 8), I see the same values for both "***old city" and "***new city" (they both show the old value), so the test method never tests the code inside the if statement, and it means that I only have code coverage until the line 9.

Can anyone help me please? I've spent almost 2 days for this test method so far and I need at least 75% code coverage for this trigger.

Just FYI, when I test the trigger manually from the Application record in Salesforce, and I update the value of "Shipping_City__c", I can see the correct and updated values for "***old city" and "***new city" in the log section; it appears that the problem should be with my test method, not with the trigger itself.

Comment: This is a textbook example of why you shouldn't use static Booleans for recursion "protection". Somehow or another, your trigger's getting called twice - probably once from an `insert` trigger or flow that does an update - such that it _doesn't run_ when you actually construct test data that exercises it.

Comment: Check out the linked questions for some alternate strategies you can adapt to this use case.

Comment: @DavidReed Thank you so much for your answer. Yes that was the cause of the issue. I commented out lines 4 and 5 and now I'm receiving 2 different values for the old and new City. Now I'm wondering how to prevent the trigger from firing twice. I'll check out the linked questions.